# How to make Mint Update launch in the background on startup?

Tags: linux, startup, cinnamon

I'm using Mint 19 (Tara) Cinnamon.

I've accidentally removed the Mint Update entry in Startup Applications and then added it again, but this time it launches in the foreground (always talking about startup).

How can I make it launch in the background again?

I've tried adding a "&" at the end of the command (by editing the entry in Startup Applications), but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What command is it exactly? Also, could you post the output of `thecommand --help`. There may be a background flag.

Comment: Also, what exactly is it "talking about"?

Comment: I would guess that the original entry was actually a script that only launched the update manager if updates existed

Comment: The command is `mintupdate`. I tried running `mintupdate --help` but it has no output, it only launches the Update Manager.

And no, the Update Manager used to launch in the background every time on startup, and then it checked for updates. Most of the time there were none.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution.

There's a different command for launching the Update Manager minimized (in the system tray), the `mintupdate-launcher` command.